# Add items to an Array of Ref with typegoose

Tags: mongoose

I got 2 classes extending `Typegoose` (`Item` and `Player`)

In the `Player` class i got an Array of `Ref<Item>[]`

```
    @arrayProp({itemsRef: Item})
    items?: Ref<Item>[];
```

In my `PlayersService`, i use this method to push an `Item`:

```
    async pushItem( itemPlayerDto: {playerId: string, item: Item}) : Promise<Player> {
        let player = await this.findById(itemPlayerDto.playerId);
        player.items.push(itemPlayerDto.item);
        return await new this.playerModel(player).save();
}
```

But when i retrieve `Players`, their `items` are not pupolated, only an `Array of ObjectId`.

```
    async findAll(): Promise<Player[]> | null {
        return await this.playerModel.find().exec();
}
```

PS: i'm using Typegoose with nestjs and netsjs-typegoose

Answer (score 5):

Ok so this is how you can populate a Ref item from a typegoose class (use: populate method) :

```
async findByName(playerName: string): Promise<Player> | null {
    let player = await this.playerModel.findOne({'displayName': playerName}).exec();
    let playerWithItems = await player.populate({
        path: 'items',
        model: 'Item'
    }).execPopulate();
    return playerWithItems;
}
```