# How to mongoose-autopopulate populate with typegoose

Tags: mongodb, typescript, auto-populate

I am using nest js with mongodb and
for the mongodb modelling i am using **Typegoose** . they did not have autopopulate functionality yet.

I am using

> https://github.com/szokodiakos/typegoose

and just want to use auto populate

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate

Comment: Please provide details on what have you tried and tested for achieving your above requirement. Probably then people in the community would be able to help you.

Comment: Manual populate is possible, as per post https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837725/2727080

Answer (score 4):

There is an `autopopulate` option for the `prop` decorator, which is used like so:

```
import { prop, Ref } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

class Person {
  @prop()
  name: string
}

class User {
  @prop({ autopopulate: true, ref: Person })
  person: Ref<Person>;

  @prop()
  password: string;
}
```

Comment: Doing just this will not work, at least with the current typegoose 7.2.0. You need to install the auto-populate plugin

Answer (score 2):

I had to use something like this:

```
import { prop, Ref, plugin } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import mongooseAutoPopulate from 'mongoose-autopopulate';

@plugin(mongooseAutoPopulate as any)
class Person {
  @prop()
  name: string
}

class User {
  @prop({ autopopulate: true, ref: Person })
  person: Ref<Person>;

  @prop()
  password: string;
}
```

If I try to use it as in docs:

```
import * as autopopulate from 'mongoose-autopopulate'; 

@plugin(autopopulate as any)
```

I get this error:
`Error: First param to 'schema.plugin()' must be a function, got "object"`

Answer (score 1):

Here we have 3 collections shops, owners, documents, gumasta.
shops having ObjectId as a reference of owner and documents. But gumasta's reference is in the owner collection document. So to populate sub sub document use
below code in typegoose.

```
     const vehicleEntity = await ShopModel.findOne({ "id": id })
        .populate({
            path: 'owner',
            populate: {
                path: 'gumasta',
                model: 'Gumasta'
            }
        })
        .populate('documents')
        .exec();
```

Actual structure of shops is

```
shops{
id: "string"
name: "string"
address_short: "string",
owner: ObjectId('asddsfsdfsdfs34csd7d') // Reference of owner data in owner collection
,documents: [ObjectId('asddsfsdfsdfs34csd7e'), ObjectId('asddsfsdfsdfs34csd7f')]
}
```

and owner has data below

```
owners{
 id
 shop_id
 reg_no
 gumasta: ObjectId('sdfsdfsdfs343')
}
```

Comment: OP said he wants it to be auto-populated, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Typegoose has an `autopopulate` option on the `prop` decorator just like @Mateja has said in his answer. However, it doesn't work by itself, you first need to install [auto-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate) plugin and set up your entity like so...

```
import { prop, Ref } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import * as autopopulate from 'mongoose-autopopulate'; // <= import the plugin

@plugin(autopopulate as any) // <= set it up here
class Person {
  @prop()
  name: string
}

class User {
  @prop({ autopopulate: true, ref: Person }) // <= enable the option
  person: Ref<Person>;

  @prop()
  password: string;
}
```

For more information, check the [Typegoose Documentation](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/integration-examples/common-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

this is a full example... But I was using ***type-graphql*** instead of ***NestJS***. It works Great!!!

```
import { prop as Property, getModelForClass, Ref, plugin, pre } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import mongooseAutoPopulate from 'mongoose-autopopulate';
import slugify from 'slugify';
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
import { departmentEnum } from '../../../helpers/validEnums';
import schemaOptions from "../../../helpers/schemaOptions";

@pre<Category>('save', function () {
  this.slug = slugify(this.name,{lower: true});
})

@ObjectType({description:'The category model class'})
@plugin(mongooseAutoPopulate as any)
export default class Category {
  @Field(() => ID, {name: 'id'})
  readonly _id: ObjectId;

  @Field(() => Date)
  readonly createdAt: Date;

  @Field(() => Date)
  readonly updatedAt: Date;

  @Field()
  @Property({required: true, unique: true})
  name!: string;

  @Field(() => departmentEnum)
  @Property({ required: true, enum: departmentEnum })
  department!: departmentEnum;

  @Field()
  @Property({required:true, default:'icon_default.png'})
  icon!: string;

  @Field()
  @Property({ unique: true, index:true })
  slug?: string;

  @Field(() => Boolean)
  @Property({default: false, type: () => Boolean})
  leaf!: boolean;

  @Field(() => Category, { nullable: true })
  @Property({ref: ()=>Category, default: null, autopopulate: { maxDepth: 1 }})
  parent?: Ref<Category>

  @Field(() => [Category], { nullable: 'items' })
  @Property({ref: ()=>Category, default: [], autopopulate: { maxDepth: 1 }})
  children!: Ref<Category>[]
}

export const CategoryModel = getModelForClass(Category,{schemaOptions: schemaOptions});
```